# CakePHP - authentication component, using a different table name and column name

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Just for organization sake, I wanted to use a different table for the authentication component to check, but it doesn't quite work. While I can initially state:

`$this->Auth->userModel = "CoreUsers"` plus set the loginAction to my proper MVC
works to look at that table just to confirm it's there, but the login doesn't work, it only keeps returning an incorrect password. Something happens in the authentication component; I can't tell what makes it fail. When I rename my table to "Users", it works.

The other part is I'd prefer to actually use the column name of 'email' rather than 'username' since that's really what I'm using anyway.

I am just not having luck finding a complete tutorial and reference sets to do both these successfully with CakePHP 2.x. What is the way forward?

References:

1. Stack Overflow question *[How do I use a table other than "Users" for CakePHP's AuthComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437911)*
2. Stack Overflow question *[CakePHP - 'AuthComponent' with a different model name (not 'User')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286927)*

(I had a look for answers, but I never quite got the whole answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your database table "core_users" and model "CoreUser" exists.

When you setup component you can put login/logout redirect here.

```
var $components = array(
        "Auth" => array(
             'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index'),
             'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'core_users', 'action' => 'login')
              ),
       "Session");
```

Now in beforeFilter medhod you can put the following

```
function beforeFilter(){
      $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
         AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'CoreUser', 'scope' => array("CoreUser.status" => 1), "fields" => array("username" => "email", "password" => "your_password_field"), 'Form', 'Basic'
                                        );
}
```

Above example you can ignore status, if you need to pass any other info on the login verification u can use that. Now about you can remove 'Basic' if you only need form validation. 
I hope this would work .

Comment: The redirects work fine, thanks. but the login fails, just gets stuck thinking it's an incorrect password/email combo.

Comment: This worked, after I found my 'userModel' was plural when it should have been singular.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

First, model names are generally singular. Are you sure you didn't mean `CoreUser` which would look in the `core_users` table?

Secondly, you can use the `email` field instead of `username` by setting the `fields` key on your auth setup.

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'CoreUser',
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

See [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) for more information.

Comment: As for the model names, most of the examples and and CakePHP tutorial has the model name as singular.  But I'll double check.

Comment: Oh man terrible typo on my part! Yes singular that's what I meant. Your post shows a plural one.

Comment: I missed the highlight of the actual 'userModel' reference should have been singular, my tables were correctly named but that line I had wrong.  Thanks.